# Lightning - How to use force:inputField?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-platform

I've seen that since Spring'15, there are new standard components available in Lightning.

I've been looking for a component that would be a sort of `apex:inputField`, but in Lightning. The `force:inputField` component seems to be what I want, however I was not able to make it work.

The component is available inside the Documentation App (/auradocs/reference.app), but there is nothing about it inside the Spring'15 Release Notes so I wonder if this component is fully available or not.

I wrote a really basic test to display an Account Name. I've set the attribute type to Account, using `type="Account"` in my `aura:attribute` tag but that is not working. Maybe am I missing something about the correct way to set it ?
Here is my code :

**LIGTHNING COMPONENT**

```xml
<aura:component controller="[YOURNAMESPACE].AccountController" implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}" />
</aura:component>
```

**COMPONENT CONTROLLER**

```javascript
({
    doInit: function(component, evt, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
                component.set("v.account", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

**APEX CONTROLLER**

```
public class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccount() {
        return [select Id, Name from Account Limit 1];
    }
}
```

However, using `<ui:inputText value="{!v.account.Name}" />` instead of `<force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}" />` is working.

Did someone manage to use it ?

Comment: Fabien, can you post what you've tried? Presumably, like the Visualforce `apex:inputField` VF tag, you'd need to bind it to something that was a field of an sObject, not just plain-old data in some JS property or random JSON object. Can you try binding it to a component attribute that is some sObject type and give it a go. If I have a chance to try tomorrow, I'll give it a go, too as I am curious.

Comment: Thanks @Peter I've edited my question to add my code samples.

Comment: And just to do a check: you are trying this on a Spring 15 org, right?

Comment: Yes, I tried on a Spring '15 org ;-)

Comment: Weird...I have it working in one instance, but not another. As UI to enter a new record, it works. But getting failures on retrieving and populating with existing data. I've got to get on with something else...but I'll try a few more tests later.

Comment: Fab, are you getting an error message?

Comment: Yes I have an internal server error now !

Comment: update: I am making progress hunting down why this is happening, but probably won't have answer until tomorrow at earliest.

Comment: Hi Peter, Fad, did you have any update on it? I'm having same issue when use force:inputField. Unfortunately, there was a problem. <<Please try again. If the problem continues, contact Salesforce Customer Support with the error ID shown here and any other related details. An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1157715112-22009(1010169736) . >> Thanks.

Comment: ..I guessing maybe it is related to the use of the component,  it is an "abstract" type, maybe we are trying to use it incorrectly? ( it also happen with force:outputField)

Comment: @Carolina Maybe it's this, that's a good point. However, I tried to create a new component extending force:inputField, and even though it's not crashing anymore, it's behaving the same way as ui:inputField. Also, I have one of my Developer Org that is on Summer 15, and that doesn't change anything. And there is no new components under the force namespace :'(

Comment: Hey guys. I am currently looking for an answer to this as well. Did anyone have anymore updates on this one?

Comment: @Fab. I've answered this below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a current shortcoming of those components.

As explained to me by Doug Chasman, `force:inputField` and `force:outputField` have always been provided the metadata definition of what the sObject was by their containing component (for instance `force:recordEdit`). At some point they will be able to do so on their own, but for now, we need to help them.

The way to do this is to provide a default value object to the `Account` attribute, like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }"/>
```

I just tested this out, and it works for me it works to get rid of the error.

Comment: Thanks Peter, is it possible for you to ask Doug about the disabled picklists (see answers from @Andrew and me below)? I would like to use this approach in a bigger Community project on production and I need to know if this feature is ready for prime time right now. In my tests, it works fine with my workaround and this would be lightyears ahead of going back to ui:inputWhatever

Comment: I've also logged a premier support case to that issue. The number is 12672526 and I'm in contact with Akash there - just in case it might help to streamline the communication. At the case I linked the relevant articles here, too, to avoid redundancy as much as possible.

Comment: Hi @Peter - I've an issue to use this technique inside an `<aura:iteration>` and asked this as a different question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97184/how-to-use-forceinputfield-and-forceoutputfield-inside-an-auraiteration - in case you have any idea how this could work, it would help me a lot. Obvious stuff like `default="{ sobjectType: 'Opportunity[]' }"` and `default="{ sobjectType: 'List<Opportunity>' }"` I've tried already unfortunately without success...

Comment: @UweHeim or @Peter Hi,  I've got an issue displaying `force:inputField` inside a `slds` modal dialog of lightning component in a visualforce page.  Could you please share us your thoughts, if you came across the same issue before? Posted my question here.http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161197/forceinputfield-is-not-displaying-inside-a-slds-modal-dialog-box-lightning-in/161201?noredirect=1#comment240007_161201

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code using what Peter provided.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

  <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" default="{ sobjectType: 'Task' }"/>


  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.Subject}" />

  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.Description}" />

  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.Priority}" />

  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.ActivityDate}" />

  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.WhoId}" />

  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.WhatId}" />

</aura:component>
```

I only found the following issues.

1. Lookup fields are not styled correctly and look pretty bad.
2. Picklists and multipicklists are disabled by default. They load the correct data but can not be selected.

If anyone knows how to fix these two issues let me know.

Comment: The question about picklists has already been asked by @UweHeim. The Lookup field question should be asked as a *new question*, not as an answer to this question. Andrew, it looks like you're new to SFSE, please take a moment to read up on topics like http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask as well as http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer. Not following the rules of a Stack Exchange is likely to get your posts flagged, voted down, or deleted. Thanks! And welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the coaching on this @Peter. I've submitted a new question [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/97046/25732) and linked to the related questions. I wish I could have just commented on your answer rather than submitting another "answer", but my reputation is too low to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use it for picklists to some degree [in the context of this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96510/how-to-populate-picklist-values-in-lightning-componets-according-to-the-metadata). My component is designed to run on a Community created by the Community Builder using the Napili-Template.

[image]

As @Andrew explained, the picklist will be rendered disabled for an yet unknown reason... To overcome this flaw, I used jQuery. Believe it or not the Napili-Template comes out-of-the-box with jQuery loaded from /sfsites/assets/Scripts/jquery/jquery.js - thank you so much for that!

The shipped jQuery is a pretty old version back from 2011, but still fine to do workarounds with one-liners. For Standalone Lightning Apps however jQuery is NOT loaded and you need to take care on you own. This seems to be important [to see error-messages as explained here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96531/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-lightning-components-used-in-the-community-builde).

**The result works for me to read and write data like this:**

**Component elfL1.cmp**

```xml
<aura:component controller="elfL1" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="account"  type="Account" default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }" />
    <h1>Test1</h1>
    <form>
        <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}" class="form-control uiInput--input input" />
        <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Type}" class="elfForceEditable" />
        <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Rating}"  class="elfForceEditable"  />
        <!--The following is the way we do NOT want to proceed-->
            <!-- <ui:inputText aura:id="client"-->
            <!-- label="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}"-->
            <!-- class="form-control"-->
            <!-- value="{!v.account.Name}"-->
            <!-- placeholder="test"-->
            <!-- />-->
        <br />
        <ui:button class="form-control" aura:id="button" label="Save" press="{!c.save}"/>
        <br /><br />
    </form>
</aura:component>
```

First I mark the wrongly disabled selects with the class `elfForceEditable`.
Second I think even the styling is OK for a starter. I just added the classes u`iInput--input` and `input` for the plain text field (Salesforce should make this consistent). The picklist got the styling right on it's own.

**Clienside controller elfL1Controller.js**

```javascript
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('elfL1.init()');
        var action2 = component.get("c.getAccount");        
        action2.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.account", response.getReturnValue());
            $('select.elfForceEditable').removeAttr('disabled');    
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action2);
    }, 
    save : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('save:1');
        var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
        var account = component.get("v.account");
        action.setParams({"account": account});
        action.setCallback(this, function() {  console.log('SAVED.');  } );
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        console.log('save:end');
    },
})
```

Here comes the one-liner workaround: I just remove the disabled attribute with `$('select.elfForceEditable').removeAttr('disabled');`

**APEX controller elfL1.cls**

```
public class elfL1 {
    @AuraEnabled public static Account          getAccount(){
        return (Account) Database.query( ' SELECT Name,Type,Rating FROM Account LIMIT 1 ' )[0];
    }
    @AuraEnabled public static Account          saveAccount(Account account){
        upsert account;
        return account;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right, I tried to play with the picklist too, and it's disabled even though it should. However, all values are here, and just removing the "disabled" attribute make the picklist work. Maybe it's just a bug on the component, setting this disabled attribute on picklist even when it shouldn't ?

Comment: Uwe, this seems like it might be a better answer to your question that you referenced in your answer, don't you think? @Fab.'s question is about getting the error to not appear. Yours is about picklists. It is a good work-around, by the way. And the "disabled" does seem like a bug to me.

Comment: @Peter : he asks explicitly for it "If anyone knows how to fix these two issues let me know." so I provided it here, too. There is obviously a bit of redundancy in these questions as it happens. Yeah, I think too, that it looks like a bug. Unfortunately there are even more bugs... I'll post them as soon as I can.

Comment: You're answering an answer. Not the original question. I also suggested that answer become a new question. I'm not saying this shouldn't be an answer somewhere. It should. Just not on Fab.'s original question at the top. :-)

Comment: Yes, @Peter you are right. Somehow I didn't have realized that there was a question in an answer already...