# How to get Look up field onto a lightning component in Salesforce1?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app

I am trying to create a lightning component for mobile  in which i need to pull Account Name field on the lead object.

I referred Salesforce documnetation but they havent given how to call relationship fields on Lightning page .

Please help me with this .

Answer (score 5):

You will have to spin your own lookup component .

Take a look at below blog and it has sample code

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-lightning-inputlookup-missing-component.html

You can use new SLDS design on top of this code to make it look like new lightning

http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups