# Lightning Page Lookup is not rendering properly

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

VF Page code:

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
                <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="input-02">Secondary Opportunity Owner:</label>
                <apex:inputfield styleclass="slds-input" value="{!opp2.Secondary_Opportunity_Owner__c}"/>
              </div>
```

Issue:
[image]

Expected:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me how to get the lookup field as expected above.

Reagrds,

Ajay

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92699/ ?

Comment: I have already got the standard lookup feature. However this is bit tricky one along with drop down as you see.

Comment: did you try setting the width for the input field?

Comment: @cartman: I did add the width, and width is reduced for outer layer. However how do I get lookup icon to select the user?

Comment: Did you try to tweak the css applied on the div & input field? Open Developer Tools in chrome or firefox and try to remove the applied classes one by one and see which one is responsible for the lookup icon to disappear.