# Lightning inputfield on a lookup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm having difficulties,

Here is the code and setup :

```
 <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="CustomObject__c">
 <lightning:inputField aura:id="accCompId" fieldName="PAccount__c" onchange="{!c.updatePersonInfo}"/>
 <lightning:inputField aura:id="signCompId" fieldName="Signatory__c" onchange="{!c.updateContactInfo}"/>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Here is the result when I try to look for an existing record that the user has access to (on left panel it's the lookup inputfield, on right panel it's the record page)

[image: Contact not found from lookup inputfield]

The inputfield for PAccount__c is giving me the results based on the text search, but the Signatory__c (lookup to Contact) isn't. I checked the filter, profile, OWD, all seems correct. Any idea why can't the user see the contacts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know `lightning:recordEditForm` doesn't work as expected with lookups when you try to create records, it should be ok to use if you edit existing records only.

So the options are:

- use custom lookup component
- set the lookup Id value if you know the Id upfront

Check out [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92163/lookup-field-in-lightning) as well.