# apex:InputField Equivalent in Lightning framework

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, lightning-aura-components, inputfield, lightning-design-system

I am new to **Lightning** framework. I imported lightning design system files into the **visualforce** page. Now I wan to use **apex:inputfield** with lightning design.

I don't want to use html  tag because I don't know the type of input. 
Like apex:inputfield display input tag based on type of value in "**value**" attribute. You don't explicitly have to mention the type of input field.

What Do I have to do to achieve the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to the [documentation for the ui class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ui_overview.htm), as well as [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield), it does not seem this is possible. You could always create text fields, and try to set the type later if possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't use ui components, but use force components.
Example is below and you can find it in auradocs.

```
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }"/> 
<force:inputField value="{!v.account.Name}" />
```