# What is the best way to debug Lightning Components (used in the Community Builder)?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, debugging

I have a lightning component `elfTest1` used on a page `elf`. The page itself is used as internal URL in the community builder wired via the menu.

Now in case of a JavaScript error in elfTest1Controller.js and when loading the error-page in the community builder, it rerouts to `/s/error`, which shows a 'Invalid Page' at the content-area, with not much information.

Now my code is simple and I provoked the error on purpose and I know exactly where it is.

But in case of complex projects dealing with non-trivial errors in JavaScript, where can I see some debug information? In the browser console I see three ajax calls (from aura_proddebug.js) but they are all successful - even in case of errors. The responses are very verbose, hard to read - I'm not sure if they are intended to be read by humans... also I found no error in there... So is there an other place to look?

[image]

How do you test-run your component in a page? Where is the best place to get readable debug information, with at least the error-line-number or a stacktrace (which is usually running nice out-of-the box in the browser console)?

Hopefully you don't point me straight to the developer console. I'm already afraid you will... At this moment I don't use it and I don't like it.

Is it possible to turn that routing completely OFF? Not to stick on the URL makes it impossible to reload the page again after a code-fix by pressing F5, instead we need to navigate back by clicking the menu. On the other hand always clicking the menu, does not bring up the current version of all components but a cached version. This is misleading somehow.

**Lightning Components - Debug Mode**

In the setup at Develop > Lightning Components there is a checkbox "Enable Debug Mode", which I have already checked. I can see a difference only in the Lightning Experice UI, but not in the Community created by Community Builder. Does this Debug Mode play together with the Community or not?

Answer (score 3):

One of the techniques I use to debug is create a lightning App and use the component inside the app and only once it is perfectly ready I host it on community .

The problem with community is everytime you change you have to preview and publish and that takes lot of time .

Instead create a lightning App .A sample below

```
<aura:application>
  <c:MorgageComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

You can open in SFDC with URL /c/MortgageApp.app where MortgageApp is the App name and then you can debug in the browser console .This is really simpler compared to debugging with community skin .

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. Hopefully we get better ways to see the logs inside the community soon. In complex cases the replication into a Lightning App will be time-wasting and error-prone. Though, for now it's surely better than nothing!

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention, that even if you have not activated the critical update "Lightning Component usage requires My Domain" to run the component in an App (using URL like /c/MortgageApp.app) WILL REQUIRE a My Domain immediately. Otherwise you get only "Lightning components require My Domain. Please contact your system administrator for more information."

Comment: Shortly after having the My Domain configured and deployed, I get another fancy error: "An error has occurred in the following section: [Exception, DomainNotPropagated]. Salesforce.com has been notified of this error." - Hopefully this will propagate and disappear soon by itself... - a really huge trip just to see that javascript-error from my question... ;-)

Comment: I am completely amazed at how bad salesforces ability to debug lightning is. They are pushing us all to lightning and want this to be the future of salesforce development. You constantly get some of the vaguest errors I have ever seen. "Something has gone wrong"??? rarely do you see anything of any use. No line numbers. no method or function failed on. WOW very poor

Comment: And it is still like that, I don't even know why they do it like this. What is the benefit?