# Javascript doesn't send value to server

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am not getting server side values in my javascript.

**Markup**

```
<aura:component controller="ContactListController">

    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contacts}" var="contact">
        <p>{!contact.Name}</p>
        <p>{!contact.Phone}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**Script**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.findAll");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            component.set("v.contacts", a.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class ContactListController {
    public static List<Contact> findAll() {
        return [SELECT id, name, phone FROM Contact LIMIT 50];
    }
}
```

Comment: what does a.getReturnValue() return? you should at least try to debug a bit before asking. Also case sensitivity is important, contact.Name != contact.name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed @AuraEnabled notation in your server-side(Apex Controller)

```
  public with sharing class ContactListController {
   @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Contact> findAll() {
    return [SELECT id, name, phone FROM Contact LIMIT 50];}}
```

The @AuraEnabled annotation enables client- and server-side access to an Apex controller method. Providing this annotation makes your methods available to your Lightning components.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add some error handling in your code, this way, you wont end up posting questions here every time you run into something -->
[Throwing and Handling Errors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_throw_error.htm)

```
  function(components, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {

                    //DO SOMETHING
                }
                else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                    console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                    // Show offline error
                }
                else if (status === "ERROR") {
                    console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                    // Show error message
                }
```

for future reference: You should check [How do I debug my lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185938/how-do-i-debug-my-lightning-component)

Also as mentioned in my comment, case sensitivity is important in Javascript. Happy Coding!