# How to find invalid lightning code before it causes an error?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

**Why this is not a duplicate:** This question is different than [How do I debug my lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185938/how-do-i-debug-my-lightning-component)  My issue was caused by a missing attribute on a Lightning component. It would be nice to see some kind of error indicating a required attribute is missing instead of a generic error message.

**Original question:**

When I include my custom component (.cmp) inside of a standalone lightning app page (.app), I get a generic error:

[image]

`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1165864723-88707 (1861465479)`

To find out more details about what is causing the issue, I have:

1. Enabled debug mode so that I get un-minified js code.
2. Disabled caching
3. Installed Lightning Inspector for Chrome

When I load the page, I do not see errors in the Google Dev Tools console or Lightning console. I'm lost as far as how to find out details about the error...

**Code**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
<!-- Header -->
<lightning:layout class="slds-page-header" >
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <lightning:icon iconName="custom:custom54" />
    </lightning:layoutItem>    
    <h1>
         Friends with Boats
    </h1>
</lightning:layout>
<lightning:layout>
        <c:BoatSearchForm />  <!-- the error happens when I include this component-->
</lightning:layout>

</aura:application>
```

**How I debugged the issue**

To find out the cause, I commented out the contents of the entire component and uncommented different sections until I ran into the problem. The error happened when I tried to add a [lightning:select](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm) component to the page. The problem -
 a missing required attribute 'label'.

```
    <lightning:select>  <!-- missing attributes: 'name' and 'label' caused the error -->
            <option value="">All types</option>
    </lightning:select>
```

**Takeaways:**

- If a lightning component requires certain attribute and it is missing, you will get a runtime error on a standalone .app page.
- A lightning markup code can be saved even though it might be missing required attributes that cause runtime errors.
- Currently, Salesforce does not show a detailed error for invalid lightning markup. You only see a generic error.
- Adding a component to an App page through App Builder does not generate this error. Instead, when you open an app page in a tab, it generates a 'WARNING' in the Google Chrome Development Console. Is this a bug or by design?
  [image]

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @glls I updated the question with code. The error occurs when I include the <c:BoatSearchForm /> component. Also, although it would be good to find the answer to this specific issue, my question is broader. That is, given such a generic error message, how would one get more details about what's causing the issue?

Comment: it comes down to the same as [How do I debug my lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185938/how-do-i-debug-my-lightning-component)

Comment: @glls  That question has a lot of good info and I've tried the suggested solutions. I've looked at Logs on the server side (Salesforce Dev console) as well as on the client side (Chrome console/lighting console) but I still do not see more information about the error.

Comment: maybe you are not looking in the right places or missed something. maybe you can explain how your qeustion is different and mention that in your post? and if i understand correctly, shouldnt you be debugging your component, since it is the one that causes the error?

Comment: @glls I agree, I might be missing something but what? :) I have to debug my component and it would help to see what's causing the issue. For example, I am able to use this component by adding it to an App Page using App Builder, but adding it to a standalone app doesn't work. No errors anywhere but the generic error. I'll keep digging.

Comment: if you need help, do post your component code alongside any errors you might spot ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70519/discussion-between-dev-e-loper-and-glls).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a try{}catch{} in the controller of  .
System.Debug() error info may be helpful.

Comment: That is a good idea. However, currently, all of the code is in the UI. Neither component nor the app file is linked to a controller.