# Typecast/Assign data from event.detail or event.target to Salesforce custom object

Tags: lightning-web-components, imperativeapex

I am trying to pass Salesforce object record to imperatively called apex method.
Javascript method is being called from onsubmit of record-edit-from, which in turn calls apex method.
But assignment from event.detail or event.target to salesforce object record is not working.

```
    @track newContactStage;
        error;

// Function is called from onsubmit of record-edit-from
submitContact(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        alert('calling function1 : submitContact' + event.detail); // Shows values from record-edit-form
    
        **this.newContactStage = event.target.value;  // Not working , assigning event.detail or event.target to contact object record**
    
        console.log('calling function3 : submitContact' + this.newContactStage);
    
        getContactStageRecords({ContactStage: this.newContactStage}) // Not getting called 
        .then(result => {
            console.log('result');
           
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.error = error;
            console.log('result error' +this.error);
        });
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your `submitContact` method is being called from the submitting of the form, it's going to contain a lot more than just a single value.

i.e. You're assigning `event.target.value` to `this.newContactStage`, however `event` will contain a whole bunch of information from the form.

You need to get the field value from your event.  The event will contain all the fields, structured as a JS object.

To get a single field value, you should be able to use:  `event.detail.fields.My_Field__c`

---

It sounds to me you don't know how to debug your lightning component. If you did, you wouldn't need to ask this question.

For more information about debugging lighting components, try this: [How do I debug my lightning component?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185938/how-do-i-debug-my-lightning-component)