# force:inputfield does not render in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am facing an issue in lightning where force:inputfield is not rendering at all. 
Here is the code:

```
    <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" >
        <aura:attribute name="newBPTask" type="Cost_Authorization__c"
             default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Cost_Authorization__c',
                             'Name': '',
                             'Pending_Approval_Amount__c' : 0
                             }"/>
      <!-- Input Form using components -->
      <div class="container">
        <form>
                <force:outputField value="{!v.newBPTask.Pending_Approval_Amount__c}"/>
                <force:inputField aura:id="RequestBudget"  value="{!v.newBPTask.Pending_Approval_Amount__c}" required="true"/>
        </form>
      </div><!-- ./container-->
    </aura:component>
```

I am sure I am doing a silly mistake but could not find. Could anyone look into this and suggest?

Comment: Thanks @Eric , I have already gone through that post.It seems, there they faced this issue only when they use fields inside <article></article>. In my case, I am just trying to render a field.

Comment: Ok, then this post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield

Comment: It is close to my question. But still in my case, I have already used <aura:attribute> as suggested there to link object type and have set a "default" but no success. This component "force:inputField" is so confusing. Not sure what I am missing here or doing wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `<label>` or `<div>` tags? I've always avoided using those `<force:outputField>` and `<force:inputField>` because they have caused some issues.

Comment: There is no specific reason for not using <label> or <div>. I just wanted to see behavior of <force:inputField> but seems there is no consistency in rendering of this component(inputfield). All, I just want to know what is wrong in above implementation.