# force:inputField error: AuraRuntimeException: Error Retrieving Field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, inputfield, lightninginput

I am getting the above error with this component, which is used as an action override on the Account object:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global" >  
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{ SObjectType: 'Account' }"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.account.Business_Name__c}"/>
</aura:component>
```

The full error message is:

> aura://ComponentController:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.AuraExecutionException:
>   ui.force.components.controllers.field.InputFieldProvider:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: Error Retrieving
>   Field for: v.account.Business_Name__c

What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: Provide an Id for the default value or associate an account record by queryibg in apex controller. You have set sobjecttype amd input field needs a record reference

Comment: @Rao This is supposed to be an input form for a new Account record. I just followed several online suggestions, including this SFSE post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield

Comment: I am guessing it is because of the default= SobjectType, lightning is case sensitive, make it default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }"/> and see if the error resolves

Comment: @Rao Tried it and didn't work :( Also tried putting sobjectType in quotes, just to be safe, and same thing.

Comment: is Business_Name__c a lookup/multiselect field?

Comment: @Rao Hey! It was the case-sensitivity of sobjectType!! It seems my browser didn't get the updated code when I refreshed it yesterday (not sure why Chrome takes a while to clear its cache -Edge doesn't have this problem..). I created a fresh new component containing Eric's code and it worked.

Comment: Mischief managed :D!!! Phew

Comment: I thought for a sec, I found the solution. I am getting same error message for Campaign__c field. It is lookup to standard campaign object. 

Here is the component code

<aura:component controller="MyController"
    implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="cmp" type="Custom_Object__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Custom_Object__c' }"/>
    <aura:handler value="{!v.cmp.Campaign__c}" name="change" action="{!c.getChildRecords}"/>
    <force:inputField aura:id="campaignName" value="{!v.cmp.Campaign__c}" required="true"/></aura:component>

Comment: Well, my issue was because of missing namespace in object and field. I would have deleted by previous comment but it may help someone who stumbles on this thread for the same reason I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sObjectType was not the proper case (with the case you have I get the same error). Also note that it works with and without the sobjectType in the single quote, here I have it in the single quote.

This works for me when placed on the Account Lightning Page (Bundle version 40.0):

```
<aura:component description="myTestComponent" implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'Account' }"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.account.CustomerPriority__c}"/>
</aura:component>
```

I also tested using this as an override to the new button and it worked just fine

Comment: Eric can you try a custom lookup field/ multiselect picklist?

Comment: @Rao - MultiSelect works fine. User Lookup throws a different error when clicking in the field (`Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'inContextOfRecordId' of component 'markup://c:myTestComponent {1:422;a}' is not visible`) but after closing the errors the field does work, until I click a user. But that is a different issue

Comment: Standard user lookup renders fine through force:inputfield for me, custom user lookup throws an error " "Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 887422595-11863 (-485973904)""

Comment: @Rao - At least the inconsistencies are consistent lol

Comment: I guessed the same about sobjectType and the OP seems to have issue with this component. I assume this is error has something to do with the type of the field.

Comment: @Rao - I saw that. I find when troubleshooting lightning, especially when giving answers here, it is extremely helpful to provide a self contained working example. Once that is working all the other stuff can be added in until it breaks. Thats the only reason I added this as an answer given you already stated it as a comment