# Taking apex :outputfield in lightning in salesforce

Tags: lightning

How to convert visualforce in lightning in salesforce

```
<apex:page controller="MyContactDetailController">
    <apex:form >

  <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.LastName}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.Email}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.Phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is purely output, there is now a [lightning:outputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_outputField.htm) component available. Sample code from the help:

```
<aura:component>
    <!-- Replace the record ID with your own -->
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="001XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Contact">
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Phone"/>
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Email" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="LeadSource" />
        </div>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: <apex:page controller="MyContactDetailController">
    <apex:form >

  <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.FirstName}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.LastName}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.Email}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!con1.Phone}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!Edit}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>  Convert in lightning

Comment: @AnishKumar You hadn't selected the Visualforce text and used the {} button in your question. I've done that now so the markup appears.

Comment: I have to convert this page into lightning.How can I implement this

Comment: @AnishKumar To do that work you will need to learn about Lightning Components. A place to start is https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics.

Answer (score 0):

See here the detailed info already discussed on the same issue: [Lightning - How to use force:inputField?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield)

Salesfore developer guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_outputField.htm